# Margin notes with the same behaviour as footnote?

Tags: footnotes, marginpar, marginnote, sidenotes

Heyall, I've got a question about margin notes.

I tend to put a lot of footnotes in my documents, and because of the large margin I thought I might as well put them to use by putting the footnotes in there. I did this using the sidenotes package.

Unfortunately, there are some annoying issues which I can't seem to fix.

The first is that just loading the sidenotes package seems to add on a second or so to my compile time for some reason, even on an empty document, and I'm not sure why.

The second is that, unlike footnotes, if I make a large side note, it will simply run off of the page, rather than continuing on the next one. This is an especially annoying problem when I add a note near the bottom of a page - it will almost always run over.

Has anyone else had these issues? If so, could you fix them?

Comment: I've used versions of the `tufte` classes to address problems like these.

Comment: @JPi  The tufte class?

Comment: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tufte-latex?lang=en

Comment: @JPi Is there any way to do this without changing the entire design of my document?

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215322/multiple-marginnote-commands-on-the-same-line-in-math-environment/216037?s=2|1.3498#216037  This won't run to the next page, but it will back up to fit on this page.

Answer (score 4):

I used the `marginfix` package ([ctan-link](https://ctan.org/pkg/marginfix?lang=de)) to fix the spacing of the sidenotes. Like the linked answer in the comments, it doesn't break sidenotes running of the page, but shifts them up to fit on the page. It will also prevent a long sidenote to run into the next one by backing them up until everything fits.

Code snippet:

```
\usepackage{marginfix} % floats sidenots
\usepackage{sidenotes}
```

In the document, just use

```
\sidenote{blabla}
```

as before.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue some time ago and published a question how to improve it, see here: [Tufte alike design with sidenotes crossing pagebreaks, or: Tufte made with KOMAscript](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/295864/4736) .

To make a long story short: Move footnotes into the margin is possible, if there is be to much text, it will be moved to the margin of the next page. Not really tested much.

And the maintainer of KOMAscript published a starred version of the makenotecommand, as far as I remember.