# Long sidenotes break marginfix or how to make breakable sidenotes

Tags: tufte, marginnote, sidenotes

I have some long sidenotes in my document using `tufte-latex`. If the sidenotes do not fit in the text height of the page, they disappear below the page as shown below[image: without marginfix].

An approach to this would be to adjust it with parameters of sidenote itself. `\sidenote[][-2cm]{text}`

Another suggested solution for this was to use the `maginfix` package as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/434966/bug-with-sidenotes-overflow-and-dont-continue-to-the-next-page). But for sidenotes which won't fit on the page, because of other sidenotes it shifts the entire sidenote to next page. Even this is an acceptable solution in a way. But the problem arises when there is a very long sidenote, one which exceeds the text height. In this case the compilation gives an error and the sidenote disappears completely.

`Package marginfix Error: lost some margin notes.`

What I would ideally want is that the sidenote breaks automatically on the next page when it exceeds the text height on the page it starts? How can this be accomplished?

Minimum Working Example

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}

\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{marginfix}
%compiles if marginfix is not used, but the sidenote is runs into the page end
% gives error if marginfix is used, the final output does not show any sidenote
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\sidenote{\lipsum}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `scrlayer-notecolumn` from the KOMA bundle has experimental code for side notes which can break over pages (it is also mentioned in the answer you linked too), but I can't tell you if this would work with your class.

Comment: I know you are using the `tufte-handout` class but the `memoir` class provides a `\sidebar{<text>}` macro where `<text>` is put into the margin near the top of the page and can continue on for multiple pages (which is what you are after). Multiple `\sidebar`s can be put on a page whereby they follow on from each other in the margin(s).