# Marginfigures, environments and scrlayer-notecolumn

Tags: floats, environments, koma-script, sweave, scrlayer-notecolumn

I am writing an article in Sweave (`knitr`), which is a translator from the statistical  language `R` to TeX. Whenever I produce a figure in Sweave it returns something like the following code for a figure.

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{knitrout}\small
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.969, 0.969, 0.969}\color{fgcolor}

{
\centering \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{example-image-a} 
}

\end{knitrout}
\caption{A caption.}
\label{fig:a-label}
\end{figure}
```

What I'd like to do is to implement a custom `marginfigure` environment via the `scrlayer-notecolumn` package using a solution similar to the one [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295864/tufte-alike-design-with-sidenotes-crossing-pagebreaks-or-tufte-made-with-komas). I am running into `Too many {'s.` errors, however, that I have not been able to recover.

What I would like to have is something like this:

```
\begin{marginfigure}
\begin{knitrout}\small
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.969, 0.969, 0.969}\color{fgcolor}

{
\centering \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{example-image-a}
}

\end{knitrout}
\end{marginfigure}
```

for which I have coded the `marginfigure` environment as follows:

```
\usepackage{environ}

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{marginfigure}{%      
  \expandafter\@marginfigure\expandafter{\BODY}%
}
\newcommand*\@marginfigure[1]{%
  \makenote*{%
    \begin{nonfloatfigure}#1\end{nonfloatfigure}%
  }%
}
\newenvironment{nonfloatfigure}{%
  \par\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \def\@captype{figure}%
}{%
  \end{minipage}
}
```

Doing

```
\makenote*{
\begin{knitrout}\small
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.969, 0.969, 0.969}\color{fgcolor}

{
\centering \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{example-image-a}
}

\end{knitrout}
}
```

on the other hand, works just fine.

The following is a not working example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{scrlayer-notecolumn}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{environ}

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{marginfigure}{%
  \expandafter\@marginfigure\expandafter{\BODY}%
}
\newcommand*\@marginfigure[1]{%
  \makenote*{%
    \begin{nonfloatfigure}#1\end{nonfloatfigure}%
  }%
}
\newenvironment{nonfloatfigure}{%
  \par\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \def\@captype{figure}%
}{%
  \end{minipage}
}

\newenvironment{knitrout}{}{} % provided from Sweave

\title{Hello}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

% Does not work
\begin{marginfigure}
\begin{knitrout}\small
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.969, 0.969, 0.969}\color{fgcolor}

{
\centering \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{example-image-a}
} 

\end{knitrout}
\end{marginfigure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your environment contains paragraphs. This means that the internal command should be long, so don't use the starred \newcommand:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{scrlayer-notecolumn}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{environ}

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{marginfigure}{%
  \expandafter\@marginfigure\expandafter{\BODY}%
}
\newcommand\@marginfigure[1]{% not \newcommand*
  \makenote*{%
    \begin{nonfloatfigure}#1\end{nonfloatfigure}%
  }%
}
\newenvironment{nonfloatfigure}{%
  \par\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \def\@captype{figure}%
}{%
  \end{minipage}
}

\newenvironment{knitrout}{}{} % provided from Sweave

\title{Hello}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

% Does not work
\begin{marginfigure}
\begin{knitrout}\small
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.969, 0.969, 0.969}\color{fgcolor}

{
\centering \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{example-image-a}
}

\end{knitrout}
\end{marginfigure}

\end{document}
```

[image]