# Option "hang" for sidenotes

Tags: alignment, sidenotes

First of all, I am sorry because I cannot describe the expected behavior well with words, but I hope the image explains it better.

- How can I make the text in the `\sidenote` command from the [`sidenotes`](https://ctan.org/pkg/sidenotes) package "hang"?
- I want the text in the side note aligned at the red line, just as it works in the foot note using the `\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}`.

Is there a way to make it work?

Thank you in advance.

[image]

MWE:

```tex
\documentclass[paper=a4, DIV=6]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}

\begin{document}

Hello World!\footnote{\blindtext}\sidenote{\blindtext}

\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/295864/4736 may help to increase the level of bewilderment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I grabbed the macro in the `sidenotes` package that places the sidenote mark and text and revised it.  What I did was horizontally shift the mark leftward using a right-aligned, zero-width makebox: `\makebox[0pt][r]{\textsuperscript{\thesidenote}{}~}`.  Later, outside of the macro, I shifted the `\marginparsep` 9pt to the right.  I also increased the `\marginparwidth` by 9pt as well.  Here is the result.

EDITED to address the issue when an optional argument (sidenotemark) is specified.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, DIV=6]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand \sidenotetext { o o +m }
{
  \IfNoValueOrEmptyTF{#1}
    {
      \@sidenotes@placemarginal{#2}{%
        \makebox[0pt][r]{% <--THIS WAS ADDED
          \textsuperscript{\thesidenote}{}~%
        }% <--THIS WAS ADDED
        #3}
  \refstepcounter{sidenote}
}
    {\@sidenotes@placemarginal{#2}{%
       \makebox[0pt][r]{% <--THIS WAS ADDED
         \textsuperscript{#1}~%
       }% <--THIS WAS ADDED
       #3}}
}
\makeatother
\marginparwidth=\dimexpr\marginparwidth+9pt% <--THIS WAS ADDED
\marginparsep=\dimexpr\marginparsep+9pt% <--THIS WAS ADDED
\begin{document}

Hello World!\footnote{\lipsum[4]}\sidenote{This is the
  text of my sidenote.  I want it to hang.}

\lipsum[2]\sidenote[*]{This is a secondary test when
  an optional argument is specified}

\end{document}
```

[image]