# Is it possible to get this uneven two column document format?

Tags: multicol, marginpar

I'm trying to figure out whether its possible to get a document to have something along the lines of this:

[image]

where there's like a smaller left (or right) column for notes, whose position can be controlled.

Comment: This looks like a margin par layout rather than two columns.

Comment: If you are looking for a margin comments, try '\marginpar' native command https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Margin_notes

Comment: ah yup, thats indeed what Im looking for instead. Thanks!

Comment: If you need your comments stretch over a pagebreak, KOMA-script offers the feature "scrlayer-notecolumn". See e.g. here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/295864/4736