# sidenotes `module` affects title page in OpTeX

Tags: pagestyle, sidenotes, optex

I was checking out this solution by Max Chernoff https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/689656/14423 about vertical alignment in margin notes with `OpTeX` and it works perfectly. Now, I've been trying with the commands `\tit`, `\author`, `\maketoc` and `\part` and I've noticed that no matter where I put them, such a solution affects them by making the corresponding pages have space for margin notes:

```
\report
\fontfam[EB Garamond]

\margins/2 a4 (1,3,2,2)in

\typosize[10/11.5]

\parindent=0pt
\parskip=1ex

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%PART
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcount\partnum
\eoldef\part#1{\vfil\break
   \incr\partnum \_chapnum=0 \_chapx % reset counters
   \vglue100pt
   \incr\tocrefnum \dest[toc:\the\tocrefnum] % destination from TOC and outlines
   \centerline{\typosize[20/]\bf Part \the\partnum:\quad #1} % Title
   \_ewref\_Xtoc{{0}{part}{}{}#1} % TOC line, \part has level 0
   {\nopagenumbers \vfil\break}   % single page without pageno
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\tit My Title
\author By Me

\eject
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Table of contents
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\nonum\notoc\sec Contents
\maketoc
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%sidenotes, requiere sidenote.lua y sidenote.opm
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\addto\_begoutput{%
    \ifodd\pageno%
        \sidenote_side\right%
    \else%
        \sidenote_side\left%
    \fi%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\load[sidenote]

\part First part

\chap My first chap
AAA

\lorem[1.]\sidenote{\lorem[1.]}

\lorem[2.]\sidenote{\lorem[2.]}

\def\_par{\let\_par=\par}
\lorem[3]\sidenote{\lorem[3.]}

\lorem[4.]\sidenote{\lorem[4.]}

\lorem[5.]\sidenote{\lorem[5.]}
\lorem[6.]\sidenote{\lorem[6.]}
\lorem[7.]\sidenote{\lorem[7.]}

\vfill\eject

\part Second part

\chap My second chapter

\sidenote_number=199
\def\sidenote_makemark{%
    \leavevmode%
    \raise 0.7ex%
    \hbox{\typosize[8/8]\romannumeral\sidenote_number}%
}

\def\sidenote_makeleft#1{%
    \hsize=2in\relax%
    \leftskip=0pt plus 1fill\relax%
    \rightskip=1in\relax%
    \it%
    \sidenote_makemark%
    #1%
    \vskip 1cm\relax%
}

\lorem[1.]\sidenote{\lorem[1.]}

\lorem[2.]\sidenote{\lorem[2.]}

\def\_par{\let\_par=\par}
\lorem[3]\sidenote{\lorem[3.]}

\lorem[4.]\sidenote{\lorem[4.]}

\lorem[5.]\sidenote{\lorem[5.]}
\lorem[6.]\sidenote{\lorem[6.]}
\lorem[7.]\sidenote{\lorem[7.]}

\bye
```

And this produce this:

[image: Title]

[image: toc]

[image: fp]

[image: sp]

I suspect it is not trivial but what is needed so that those pages do not have space for marginal notes?

PS: I start to think that it would also be desirable for pages intended for acknowledgments, bibliography or index to also not have space for margin notes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is all from the `\margins` command, and doesn't directly depend on the sidenotes (although the sidenotes do generally require uneven margins to have enough room). The solution is to set the margins to be equal where desired:

```tex
\fontfam[EB Garamond]
\report

% Offset two-sided left/right margins by default
\margins/2 a4 (1,3,2,2)in

% Switch to equal single-sided margins
\def\evenmargins{%
    \margins/1 a4 (1,1,,)in
}

% Define a *really* basic "part" heading
\eoldef\part#1{
    \vfil\break
    {
        \evenmargins
        \centerline{\typosize[20/]\bf Part #1}

        {\noindent \it\lorem[1]}

        {\nopagenumbers \vfil\break}
    }
}

% Front matter
{
    \evenmargins
    \tit My Title
    \author By Me

    \vfill

    \nonum\notoc\sec Contents
    \maketoc

    \vfil\eject
}

% Document body
\part One

\chap One

\lorem[1-7]

\part Two

\chap Two

\lorem[1-7]

\bye
```

[image: output]

Here, we've defined an `\evenmargins` command that will set the margins to be equal on both sides. To make sure that it only applies locally, use it inside of a group that ends with a page break.